# Limits of complicated sum.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, summation

I'm faced with something like:
$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^r \frac{\hbar^n (-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{r-n} \frac{x^i}{i!} \right)  \frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} \right] \psi = 0 $$

A huge mess, I know.  I'm not sure exactly how to simplify, and get something in terms of exponentials.

Now, obviously it'd be easiest to write this as something like:
$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^r \frac{\hbar^n (-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{min\{n,r-n\}} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=k}^{r-n} \frac{x^{i-k}}{(i-k)!} \frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} \right] \psi = 0 $$

If you apply the limit then obviously $min\{n,r-n\}=n$ and so you would simply get:
$$ [e^{-\hbar} e^x e^{-\hbar \partial_x}] \psi = 0 $$

But, I feel like there's something missing with this.  If we do this, we're neglecting the part inside the limit where $r-n<n$.

For example, if you break up the expression as:
$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{r/2} \frac{\hbar^n (-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=k}^{r-n} \frac{x^{i-k}}{(i-k)!} \frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} + \sum_{n=r/2+1}^{r} \frac{\hbar^n (-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{r-n} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=k}^{r-n} \frac{x^{i-k}}{(i-k)!} \frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} \right] \psi = 0 $$
But, how do you evaluate the limit of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind!  I found the answer, I think.

If we call $r/2=a$ in the above expression, and substitute $m=n-a+1$, then we get something like:
$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{a} \frac{\hbar^n (-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=k}^{2a-n} \frac{x^{i-k}}{(i-k)!} \frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} + \sum_{m=0}^{a+1} \frac{\hbar^{m+a-1} (-1)^{m+a-1}}{(m+a-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{a-m+1} \frac{(m+a-1)!}{k! (m+a-1-k)!} \sum_{i=k}^{a-m+1} \frac{x^{i-k}}{(i-k)!} \frac{d^{m+a-1-k}}{dx^{m+a-1-k}} \right] \psi = 0 $$

And, evaluating the limit I think that all the terms in the second sum go to zero, because of the $\frac{1}{k!(m+a-1-k)!}$.